# (Javascript) YouTube video ID from embed code - regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, youtube

I've got a script that goes through the page and returns all selected elements - in this case, `<embed...>`

For example, when a YouTube video is found in a blog, it returns an iframe. I can take the iframe src, pass it through a function, and regex the video ID. However, when the YouTube video in within a YouTube page, its embedded differently and the video ID is found within the "flashvars" attribute.

Here's an example video embed : http://pastie.org/7155840

What would you guys recommend the best way of confirming the src as YouTube, and getting the video ID `qlo5XHZ8-zI` from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that doesn't use a regex.

First confirm it as youtube:

```
if (e.src.substr(0, 19) != "http://s.ytimg.com/") return false
```

Then extract the video id:

```
// get the flashvars
var flashvars = e.getAttribute("flashvars")
// convert flashvars string to key-value pairs
flashvars = flashvars.split("&").map(function(entry) {
  return entry.split("=", 2)
})
// look up the value of the "video_id" key
var video_id = flashvars.filter(function(entry) {
  return entry[0] == "video_id"
})[0]
```

`video_id` should now be the video's ID.